# Null space of Sum of matrces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to find the null space of sum of matrices. I believe the following statement is correct:

N(A+B+C+...) ⊇ N(A) ∩ N(B) ∩ N(C) ∩ ...

However, I cannot find a proof.  I would appreciate a theoretical proof or any textbook/publication reference that I can cite. In my case, the matrices are typically square, full-rank and symmetric.

Comment: If $A, B, C, \ldots$ all annihilate a vector $v$, then so does their sum. Is this what you mean?

Comment: That's one way of looking at it.  But I only have the sum, not individual A, B, C, etc. If the above statement is correct, then if I find the null space vector v  of the sum, then the same v will also be the null-spaces of all the individual matrices.  Hope that makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: It should be the other way around. You wanted to show that the intersection is a subset of $N(A+B+C+\dots)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x \in \mathcal N(A_j)$ for $j = 1, 2, \ldots$, then $0 = A_1 x = A_2x = \ldots$, so $A_1x + A_2 x + A_3x = (\sum_j A_j)x = 0$. Therefore, $x \in \mathcal N(\sum_j A_j)$.

Note: no additional matrix structure assumptions were required.

Comment: I think I need the proof from the other direction, i.e., if  x∈N(∑jAj), then can we claim that x is also the null space of individual Aj's?

Comment: Even with your assumption, absolutely not. Take $A = \left(\matrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \right)$ and $B = \left(\matrix{-1& 0 \\ 0 & -1}\right)$. Now compute $\mathcal N (A+B)$ and $\mathcal N (A) \cap \mathcal N(B)$.

Comment: The matrices I am dealing with are positive definite covariance matrices estimated from noisy observations.  So they will never have negative diagonals as in your example. Also, I am dealing with non-zero A+B, and in my case, A+B is also positive definite covariance matrix. Given this set-up, my question again is, if C=A+B and I find the null space of C, say x, is x also the null space of A and B?  Thanks.